# Fixing Amazon Cognito - Sign In With Apple - "Invalid State/RelayState provided"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been working with Amazon Cognito User Pools and have Apple set up as an identity provider in my User Pool. After going through the OAuth2 flow to create an account with Apple, Cognito's hosted UI redirects me to a page that simply shows the error "Invalid State/RelayState provided". How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This badly-described error can be caused by failing to enable an identity provider for the app client you are using to authenticate the user.

You can enable an identity provider by doing the following:

1. Navigate to your User Pool configuration in the AWS Console
2. Choose **App Integration -> App Client Settings** in the left sidebar
3. Choose the app client (or multiple) you want to enable the provider for
4. Ensure the provider is checked under **Enabled Identity Providers**
5. Save!

Comment: You just saved my bacon! Thank you for this killer tip.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, this really helped and saved me a lot of time, hope that the  Cognito's team could eventually provide some decent reporting to help us troubleshoot these scenarios

Comment: Hint: There may be more than one client for that user pool. The first time I did not enable the identity provider for all that I required

Comment: I had to enable the provider for 2 clients, 1 only didn't work. The documentation is horrible.

Comment: App Integration > App client settings. NOT General settings > App clients